# Exclude a JavaScript file from a node

Tags: javascript

I'd like to exclude a js file from loading on to a specific node.

Right now my libraries.yml file looks like this:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css: {}
      css/style2.css: {}
      css/header.css: {}
      css/color-1.css: {}
      css/themify-icons.css: {}
      css/jquery-ui.css: {}
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/jquery-ui.js: {}
    js/popper.js: {}
    js/tooltip.js: {}
    js/wow.min.js: {}
    plugin/appear/jquery.appear.js: {}
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

I'd like to exclude the js/custom.js from loading on node/4. Alternatively I would like to load that file ONLY for the front page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Delete/Exclude** `js/custom.js` from the `global-styling` section in `THEMENAME.libraries.yml` and define it as a library at the end of the same file

```
# THEMENAME.libraries.yml
custom-js:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

And then include the library conditionally to where you want it using `THEMENAME_preprocess_page` function in `THEMENAME.theme`

```
//THEMENAME.theme
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    //include it if its front_page
    if ($variables['is_front'] == TRUE) {
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEMENAME/custom-js';
    }

    //include it if its NOT node 4
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface && $node->id() != 4) {
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEMENAME/custom-js';
    }  
}
```

For more info [read the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the file only for the front page, separate that file to another library like:

```
global-custom-styling:
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
```

And preprocess page then attach library:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  if ($variables['is_front'] == TRUE) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my-theme/global-custom-styling';
  }
}
```